# Wrong output using heap-sort (written in python)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

I have written the following heap sort code and I get the wrong output (not sorted) at times and I can't seem to find why...any help will be much appreciated!

```
def heap_sort(self, a):

    heapsize = self.build_max_heap(a)

    n = len(a)-1
    i = len(a)-1

    for i in range(i, 0, -1):
        temp = a[0]
        a[0] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp
        heapsize = heapsize - 1
        self.max_heapify(heapsize, a, 0)       #rebuild max heap at with new root

    return a

def max_heapify(self, heapsize, a, i):

    left = (2*(i+1))-1      #left child of i
    right = 2*(i+1)             #right child of i
    largest = i

    if left < heapsize and a[left] > a[i]:
        largest = left

    if right < heapsize and a[right] > a[largest]:
        largest = right

    if largest != i:
        temp = a[largest]
        a[largest] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp
        self.max_heapify(heapsize, a, largest)

def build_max_heap(self, a):

    heapsize = len(a)
    i = int(heapsize/2)-1

    for i in range(i, 0):
        self.max_heapify(heapsize, a, i)

    return heapsize
```

My tests:

```
#--Test for 0 in array--#
def zero_array(self):
    a = [12,0,232]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return

#--Test for duplicate in array--#
def duplicate_array(self):
    a = [12, 12, 7]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return

#--Test for all same values in array--#
def allsame_array(self):
    a = [1,1,1]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return

#--Test for negative values in array--#
def negative_array(self):
    a = [-23, -2, 123]
    print self.sort.heap_sort(a)
    return
```

Output (which is supposed to all be sorted):

```
    [0, 232, 12]
    [7, 12, 12]
    [1, 1, 1]
    [-2, 123, -23]
```

Comment: No need for a `temp` variable, you can just do `a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]`. You also don't appear to be doing anything with `n`.

Comment: You say "at times" does that mean that the output sorted correctly sometimes?

Comment: You can see from my tests that I test different scenarios of an array to be sent to be sorted...and some as you can see in the output work while others don't...(@Nathan - the n does something else that I commented out for testing initialization, maintenance, and termination, as for not having a temp I don't understand your replacement a[i] = a[i] ?

Comment: `a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]` will swap two variables. a[0] becomes a[i] and a[i] becomes a[0]

Comment: hmmm...I just did the replacement what ended up happening was I got the array sorted in reverse...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because your second `range()` is incrementing forwards instead of backwards.

```
for i in range(i, 0):
```

Should be:

```
for i in range(i, 0, -1):
```

You also need to keep in mind that `range()` will stop just before the second argument, so `range(5, 0, -1)` will return `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: I changed it, still getting the same wrong output...but thanks

Comment: Do you want it to include 0? If so the second part of `range()` needs to be -1.